# Cartoon Show: 4 kids transform into lizard, eagle, etc

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I can only barely remember this cartoon show but as far as I can remember there are 4 kids (I think) that when they interact with this thing they transform. As far as I can remember, the first kid is a lizard and then the other, I think the girl, becomes an eagle. It had an Aztec or Mayan civilization vibe on it.

Comment: When did you watch this? On what network? Or was this on VHS? DVD? Were the main characters white? Black? Asian? Mixed?

Comment: I watched this when I was a kid. Im 15 right now. Its a cartoon series. It has episodes. I cant really say their skin color and nationality. But it was english and there were some words that relates to aztec or mayan stuff. I just remembered, it was like they interact with this totem. Pretty sure its like a totem cartoon show amd they transform when this villain tries to stole a totem

Comment: I really looked for it and the title of this show is Combo Niños

Comment: You can post that as an answer. :) Explain why it fits, and how you eventually found it.

Answer (score 1):

As a placeholder until Janeous13 self-answers, as per his comment, this is *[Combo Niños](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_Ni%C3%B1os)*.

[image: Title image for *Combo Niños*]

> Combo Niños is an English-language French animated television series created by SIP Animation in collaboration with Jetix Europe and TF1, aimed towards the 6–10 years old audience. The series is about the adventures of 4 juvenile capoeira practitioners with the mission to protect the city of Nova Nizza from attack by mystical creatures from another dimension called "Divinos".

....

> The Combo Niños have the ability to transform into mystical beings in animal form by touching one of the totems that appear on the creatures. This form gives them unique skills that serve them in the battle against the Divinos and to perform special attacks called Big Blastico, used to return a Divino back to its own dimension.

Azul turns into an eagle and Pilar turns into an iguana.

### Opening

Comment: @Janeous13: Feel free to copy any or all of my answer for your own. If you use the "edit" link, you can even pull in formatting.