# Cartoon with kids with Mexican masks that can transform them into animals

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

A cartoon about kids that has Mexican (?) masks that can transform them into a specific animal depending on their masks if they touch that animal's icon that summons in a villain

Comment: my first thought was Mucha Lucha but I don't think that was about transforming into animals

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You could make this a better question by adding some more detail; you should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall anything else you can [edit] into your question.  For example, when did you watch this?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are probably looking for *[Combo Niños](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_Ni%C3%B1os)*.

[image: Title image for *Combo Niños*]

> ***Combo Niños*** is an English-language French animated television series created by SIP Animation in collaboration with Jetix Europe and TF1, aimed towards the 6–10 years old audience. The series is about the adventures of 4 juvenile capoeira practitioners with the mission to protect the city of Nova Nizza from attack by mystical creatures from another dimension called "Divinos".
>
> The Combo Niños have the ability to transform into mystical beings in animal form by touching one of the totems that appear on the creatures. This form gives them unique skills that serve them in the battle against the Divinos and to perform special attacks called Big Blastico, used to return a Divino back to its own dimension.

### Opening

This previously came up as [Cartoon Show: 4 kids transform into lizard, eagle, etc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205459/cartoon-show-4-kids-transform-into-lizard-eagle-etc),

Comment: If this is the work you were looking for, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: Discussion about whether or not comments such as that one ^ are acceptable has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102807/discussion-on-answer-by-fuzzyboots-cartoon-with-kids-with-mexican-masks-that-can) and to the [associated meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12860/31936).