# Cartoon where 4 elemental children fight big monsters but have to press a symbol

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

The 4 children each have an element but they have to press a symbol hidden on the skin of the enemy to activate their powers. I remember them changing into a look that represents an animal (fire was either a lion or tiger, wind was a pink butterfly, thats all i remember).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  What style was it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[Combo Niños](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_Ni%C3%B1os)*.

[image: Title image for *Combo Niños*]

> Combo Niños is an English-language French animated television series created by SIP Animation in collaboration with Jetix Europe and TF1, aimed towards the 6–10 years old audience. The series is about the adventures of 4 juvenile capoeira practitioners with the mission to protect the city of Nova Nizza from attack by mystical creatures from another dimension called "Divinos".

....

> The Combo Niños have the ability to transform into mystical beings in animal form by touching one of the totems that appear on the creatures. This form gives them unique skills that serve them in the battle against the Divinos and to perform special attacks called Big Blastico, used to return a Divino back to its own dimension.

### Opening

Comment: Also the answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224320/cartoon-with-kids-with-mexican-masks-that-can-transform-them-into-animals?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205459/cartoon-show-4-kids-transform-into-lizard-eagle-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1, the latter of which was confirmed by the querent.

Comment: Where is this series set? It's got a Spanish name, but the protagonists practice a Brazilian martial art and the name of the city looks Italian.

Comment: It's a mishmash. Mexican culture, Mesoamerican sports, Brazilian  martial art (and names), Corsican city name...